# sql server procedure for auto alert

Tags: sql-server

I am learning store procedure, I have one table name called as my.work, in the table I have columns name status, date and time
Using select query I can able to get all the status=ready and where the date=2-6-2018.

Now my question is I need to write a procedure to check the three condition (status/date/time) and if the condition is matched then it will trigger one auto email alert 15 minutes back.

Status  Date                     Time
ready   2018-02-06 00:00:00.000  16:00

Can you please some one help me on this ?

Comment: share your query.

Comment: For SP:- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/ And For Sending Mails:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql

Comment: select * from dbo.['my.work$'] where status='ready' and Date='2-9-2018' and time='16:00';

Answer (score 0):

The date comparison should be done between dates.

```
create table #mywork(WorkStatus varchar(50), WorkDate date, WorkTime time )

insert into #mywork(WorkStatus,WorkDate,WorkTime)values('ready','2018-02-06', '16:00')
insert into #mywork(WorkStatus,WorkDate,WorkTime)values('ready','2018-02-06', '17:00')
insert into #mywork(WorkStatus,WorkDate,WorkTime)values('ready','2018-02-07', '16:00')
insert into #mywork(WorkStatus,WorkDate,WorkTime)values('ready','2018-02-07', '17:00')



select *,cast('06-02-2018' as date) from #mywork where workstatus='ready' and workDate=cast('02-06-2018' as date) and worktime=cast('16:00' as time);
```

Also I will suggest you to not use SQL Keywords as your table column name.